# Apply SHA256 and Base64 to string in script

Tags: shell-script, scripting, binary, hashsum, base64

I'm trying to apply SHA256 and then Base64 encode a string inside a shell script. Got it working with PHP:
`php -r 'echo base64_encode(hash("sha256", "asdasd", false));'`. But I'm trying to get rid of the PHP dependency.

Got this line that works well in the terminal (using the `fish` shell):

```
$ echo -n "asdasd" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
X9kkYl9qsWoZzJgHx8UGrhgTSQ5LpnX4Q9WhDguqzbg=
```

But when I put it inside a shell script, the result differs:

```
$ cat foo.sh
#!/bin/sh
echo -n "asdasd" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
$ ./foo.sh
IzoDcfWvzNTZi62OfVm7DBfYrU9WiSdNyZIQhb7vZ0w=
```

How can I make it produce expected result? My guess is that it's because of how binary strings are handled?

Comment: @terdon I'm using fish shell. If I launch bash(`$ bash`) and run the script the output is the same though.

Comment: OK, but what's the output of `readlink -f /bin/sh`? What shell is your sh?

Comment: @terdon I'm on OS X so can't use readlink's -f flag. But `greadlink -f /bin/sh` is saying /bin/sh

Comment: OK, in that case, the `sh` implementation that OSX ships with has an `echo` that doesn't understand `-n`. Unlike your default `fish` shell's.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using different shells. The `echo` command is a shell builtin for most shells and each implementation behaves differently. Now, you said your default shell is `fish`. So, when you run this command:

```
~> echo -n "asdasd" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
X9kkYl9qsWoZzJgHx8UGrhgTSQ5LpnX4Q9WhDguqzbg=
```

you will get the output shown above. This is because the `echo` of `fish` supports `-n`. Apparently, on your system, `/bin/sh` is a shell whose `echo` doesn't support `-n`. If the `echo` doesn't understand `-n`, what is actually being printed is `-n asdasd\n`. To illustrate, lets use `printf` to print exactly that:

```
$ printf -- "-n asdasd\n" 
-n asdasd
```

Now, if we pass that through your pipeline:

```
$ printf -- "-n asdasd\n" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
IzoDcfWvzNTZi62OfVm7DBfYrU9WiSdNyZIQhb7vZ0w=
```

Thats the output you get from your script. So, what happens is that `echo -n "asdasd"` is actually printing the `-n` *and* a trailing newline. A simple solution is to use `printf` instead of `echo`:

```
$ printf "asdasd" | shasum -a 256 | cut -d " " -f 1 | xxd -r -p | base64
X9kkYl9qsWoZzJgHx8UGrhgTSQ5LpnX4Q9WhDguqzbg=
```

The above will work the same on the commandline and in your script and should do so with any shell you care to try. Yet another reason why [`printf` is better than `echo`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/22222).

Comment: You're right. Using `printf` instead of `echo -n` solves my issue. Thank you!

Comment: Moving away from `echo` and instead using `printf` does seem like the way to go. Two other solutions could be to make the script use Bash `#!/bin/bash` or invoke `echo` with the absolute path `/bin/echo`: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/173837/50639

Comment: @NiklasBerglund yes, but even `/bin/echo` can be different on different machines. Always use printf for maximum portability. Read the link at the end of my answer for more than you ever wanted to know about why echo should be avoided.